# Retrieve C# Attribute Data With Extension Method

Tags: c#, attributes

Looking for a way to retrieve attribute data for a property on a class (many different types) in my data layer with an extension method...

Final goal is to see the method here and be able to access the properties:

[image]

I would expect to be able to do something like (non-working code):

```
Customer c = new Customer();
int mcl = c.CustNo.GetSchemaDetails().MaxCharLength;
```

The attribute is assigned to the class property as such:

```
public class Customer
{
    [ColumnSchema("Customer", "CUST_NO")] 
    public string CustNo { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

I've created an extension method to retrieve the 'SchemaDetails' object from the 'ColumnSchemaAttribute'

```
public class AttributeExtensions
{
    public static SchemaDetails GetSchemaDetails(Type T)
    {
        ColumnSchemaAttribute csa = (ColumnSchemaAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(T, typeof(ColumnSchemaAttribute));
        return csa.SchemaDetails;
    }
}
```

Bulk of the 'ColumnSchemaAttribute' which returns db schema details for the column

```
public class ColumnSchemaAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    private string tableName, columnName;
    
    public ColumnSchemaAttribute(string TableName, string ColumnName)
    {
        tableName = TableName;
        columnName = ColumnName;           
    }
    
    private SchemaDetails schemaDetails;
    public SchemaDetails SchemaDetails
    {
        get
        {
            if (schemaDetails == null) { schemaDetails = getSchemaDetails(); }
            return schemaDetails;
        }
    }
    
    private SchemaDetails getSchemaDetails()
    {
        SchemaDetails sd = null;
    
        string sql =
                   @"
                        SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
                        LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu ON ccu.COLUMN_NAME = c.COLUMN_NAME and ccu.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
                        LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME and tc.TABLE_NAME = ccu.TABLE_NAME
                        WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName and c.COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
                    ";
    
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetConnectionString()))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection))
                        {
                    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = tableName;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = columnName;
    
                    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        sd = readData(sqlDataReader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException(ex.Message);
        }
  
        return sd;
    }
}
```

Any help regarding a way to do this or an alternative approach is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to getting any property attribute you need the retrieve the property info not the type, one way to do this is using expressions, next step after retrieving the `SchemaDetails` instance value would be to get some property value from it:

```
public static class AttributeExtensions
{
    public static SchemaDetails GetSchemaDetails<T>(this T _, Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyAccessorExpression)
    {
        if (propertyAccessorExpression.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)
        {
            if (memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
            {
                var attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnSchemaAttribute>();

                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    return attribute.SchemaDetails;
                }
            }
        }

        return default;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var customer = new Customer();
        var length = customer
            .GetSchemaDetailsFor(x => x.CustNo)
            .MaxCharLength;

        Console.WriteLine(length);
    }
```